# Grouping the multiple xml elements and show following siblings in xslt version 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am unaware of grouping the elements in XSLT.
I need to group by:

```
 <PmtInf>
          <PmtInfId>5637144610</PmtInfId>
          <PmtMtd>ARF</PmtMtd>
          <PmtTpInf>
            <SvcLvl>
              <Cd>ATGP</Cd>
            </SvcLvl>
          </PmtTpInf>
          <ReqdExctnDt>2020-06-29</ReqdExctnDt>
```

The PmtInf should repeat group by values and appending the rest of the elements sets:
Dbtr,DbtrAcct,DbtrAgt,ChrgBr,CdtTrfTxInf along with siblings.

My input xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>00000044</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2020-06-30T09:06:15</CreDtTm>
      <Authstn>
        <Cd>ADET</Cd>
      </Authstn>
      <NbOfTxs>5</NbOfTxs>
      <CtrlSum>5452.85</CtrlSum>
      <InitgPty>
        <Id>
          <OrgId>
            <Othr>
              <Id>BCD12345678</Id>
            </Othr>
          </OrgId>
        </Id>
      </InitgPty>
    </GrpHdr>
    <PmtInf>
      <PmtInfId>5637144610</PmtInfId>
      <PmtMtd>ARF</PmtMtd>
      <PmtTpInf>
        <SvcLvl>
          <Cd>ATGP</Cd>
        </SvcLvl>
      </PmtTpInf>
      <ReqdExctnDt>2020-06-29</ReqdExctnDt>
      <Dbtr>
        <Nm>MKC Group Inc</Nm>
        <PstlAdr>
          <StrtNm>1234</StrtNm>
          <PstCd>524002</PstCd>
          <TwnNm>Lake Forest</TwnNm>
          <CtrySubDvsn>IND</CtrySubDvsn>
          <Ctry>IN</Ctry>
        </PstlAdr>
      </Dbtr>
      <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <Othr>
            <Id>99999999</Id>
          </Othr>
        </Id>
      </DbtrAcct>
      <DbtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>MKMKIN33</BIC>
          <ClrSysMmbId>
            <MmbId>99999999</MmbId>
          </ClrSysMmbId>
          <PstlAdr>
            <Ctry>IN</Ctry>
          </PstlAdr>
        </FinInstnId>
      </DbtrAgt>
      <ChrgBr>DEBT</ChrgBr>
      <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <PmtId>
          <InstrId>INPP-000000090</InstrId>
          <EndToEndId>INPP-000000090</EndToEndId>
        </PmtId>
        <Amt>
          <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">4000.98</InstdAmt>
        </Amt>
        <CdtrAgt>
          <FinInstnId>
            <BIC>ABCDEFGHIJK</BIC>
            <PstlAdr>
              <Ctry>IN</Ctry>
            </PstlAdr>
          </FinInstnId>
        </CdtrAgt>
        <Cdtr>
          <Nm>MY Notes</Nm>
          <PstlAdr>
            <StrtNm>StreetNum123 Street Address 2 Address3</StrtNm>
            <PstCd>524002</PstCd>
            <TwnNm>TownNum</TwnNm>
            <CtrySubDvsn>IN</CtrySubDvsn>
            <Ctry>EA</Ctry>
          </PstlAdr>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
          <Id>
            <Othr>
              <Id>AB67BOFS80200645478001</Id>
            </Othr>
          </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
      </CdtTrfTxInf>
    </PmtInf>
    <PmtInf>
      <PmtInfId>5637144610</PmtInfId>
      <PmtMtd>ARF</PmtMtd>
      <PmtTpInf>
        <SvcLvl>
          <Cd>ATGP</Cd>
        </SvcLvl>
      </PmtTpInf>
      <ReqdExctnDt>2020-06-29</ReqdExctnDt>
      <Dbtr>
        <Nm>SLJ Group Inc</Nm>
        <PstlAdr>
          <StrtNm>98188 MK Dr Street DWAddress2 DWAddress3</StrtNm>
          <PstCd>524002</PstCd>
          <TwnNm>Lake Forest</TwnNm>
          <CtrySubDvsn>IN</CtrySubDvsn>
          <Ctry>IN</Ctry>
        </PstlAdr>
      </Dbtr>
      <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <Othr>
            <Id>999999999</Id>
          </Othr>
        </Id>
      </DbtrAcct>
      <DbtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>MKMKMKMK</BIC>
          <ClrSysMmbId>
            <MmbId>999999999</MmbId>
          </ClrSysMmbId>
          <PstlAdr>
            <Ctry>US</Ctry>
          </PstlAdr>
        </FinInstnId>
      </DbtrAgt>
      <ChrgBr>DEBT</ChrgBr>
      <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <PmtId>
          <InstrId>INPP-000000092</InstrId>
          <EndToEndId>INPP-000000092</EndToEndId>
        </PmtId>
        <Amt>
          <InstdAmt Ccy="USD">400.55</InstdAmt>
        </Amt>
        <CdtrAgt>
          <FinInstnId>
            <BIC>MKMKMKMK</BIC>
            <PstlAdr>
              <Ctry>US</Ctry>
            </PstlAdr>
          </FinInstnId>
        </CdtrAgt>
        <Cdtr>
          <Nm>Manpower Inc</Nm>
          <PstlAdr>
            <StrtNm> 50 Technology Ct.  </StrtNm>
            <PstCd>06854</PstCd>
            <TwnNm>Norwalk</TwnNm>
            <CtrySubDvsn>CT</CtrySubDvsn>
            <Ctry>US</Ctry>
          </PstlAdr>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
          <Id>
            <Othr>
              <Id>999999999</Id>
            </Othr>
          </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
      </CdtTrfTxInf>
    </PmtInf>
  </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

My desired xml output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>00000044</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2020-06-30T09:06:15</CreDtTm>
      <Authstn>
        <Cd>ADET</Cd>
      </Authstn>
      <NbOfTxs>5</NbOfTxs>
      <CtrlSum>5452.85</CtrlSum>
      <InitgPty>
        <Id>
          <OrgId>
            <Othr>
              <Id>BCD12345678</Id>
            </Othr>
          </OrgId>
        </Id>
      </InitgPty>
    </GrpHdr>
    <PmtInf>
      <PmtInfId>5637144610</PmtInfId>
      <PmtMtd>ARF</PmtMtd>
      <PmtTpInf>
        <SvcLvl>
          <Cd>ATGP</Cd>
        </SvcLvl>
      </PmtTpInf>
      <ReqdExctnDt>2020-06-29</ReqdExctnDt>
      <Dbtr>
        <Nm>MKC Group Inc</Nm>
        <PstlAdr>
          <StrtNm>1234</StrtNm>
          <PstCd>524002</PstCd>
          <TwnNm>Lake Forest</TwnNm>
          <CtrySubDvsn>IND</CtrySubDvsn>
          <Ctry>IN</Ctry>
        </PstlAdr>
      </Dbtr>
      <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <Othr>
            <Id>99999999</Id>
          </Othr>
        </Id>
      </DbtrAcct>
      <DbtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>MKMKIN33</BIC>
          <ClrSysMmbId>
            <MmbId>99999999</MmbId>
          </ClrSysMmbId>
          <PstlAdr>
            <Ctry>IN</Ctry>
          </PstlAdr>
        </FinInstnId>
      </DbtrAgt>
      <ChrgBr>DEBT</ChrgBr>
      <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <PmtId>
          <InstrId>INPP-000000090</InstrId>
          <EndToEndId>INPP-000000090</EndToEndId>
        </PmtId>
        <Amt>
          <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">4000.98</InstdAmt>
        </Amt>
        <CdtrAgt>
          <FinInstnId>
            <BIC>ABCDEFGHIJK</BIC>
            <PstlAdr>
              <Ctry>IN</Ctry>
            </PstlAdr>
          </FinInstnId>
        </CdtrAgt>
        <Cdtr>
          <Nm>MY Notes</Nm>
          <PstlAdr>
            <StrtNm>StreetNum123 Street Address 2 Address3</StrtNm>
            <PstCd>524002</PstCd>
            <TwnNm>TownNum</TwnNm>
            <CtrySubDvsn>IN</CtrySubDvsn>
            <Ctry>EA</Ctry>
          </PstlAdr>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
          <Id>
            <Othr>
              <Id>AB67BOFS80200645478001</Id>
            </Othr>
          </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
      </CdtTrfTxInf>
      <Dbtr>
        <Nm>SLJ Group Inc</Nm>
        <PstlAdr>
          <StrtNm>98188 MK Dr Street DWAddress2 DWAddress3</StrtNm>
          <PstCd>524002</PstCd>
          <TwnNm>Lake Forest</TwnNm>
          <CtrySubDvsn>IN</CtrySubDvsn>
          <Ctry>IN</Ctry>
        </PstlAdr>
      </Dbtr>
      <DbtrAcct>
        <Id>
          <Othr>
            <Id>999999999</Id>
          </Othr>
        </Id>
      </DbtrAcct>
      <DbtrAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BIC>MKMKMKMK</BIC>
          <ClrSysMmbId>
            <MmbId>999999999</MmbId>
          </ClrSysMmbId>
          <PstlAdr>
            <Ctry>US</Ctry>
          </PstlAdr>
        </FinInstnId>
      </DbtrAgt>
      <ChrgBr>DEBT</ChrgBr>
      <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <PmtId>
          <InstrId>INPP-000000092</InstrId>
          <EndToEndId>INPP-000000092</EndToEndId>
        </PmtId>
        <Amt>
          <InstdAmt Ccy="USD">400.55</InstdAmt>
        </Amt>
        <CdtrAgt>
          <FinInstnId>
            <BIC>MKMKMKMK</BIC>
            <PstlAdr>
              <Ctry>US</Ctry>
            </PstlAdr>
          </FinInstnId>
        </CdtrAgt>
        <Cdtr>
          <Nm>Manpower Inc</Nm>
          <PstlAdr>
            <StrtNm> 50 Technology Ct.  </StrtNm>
            <PstCd>06854</PstCd>
            <TwnNm>Norwalk</TwnNm>
            <CtrySubDvsn>CT</CtrySubDvsn>
            <Ctry>US</Ctry>
          </PstlAdr>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
          <Id>
            <Othr>
              <Id>999999999</Id>
            </Othr>
          </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
      </CdtTrfTxInf>
    </PmtInf>
  </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

I have used the below XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:ns1="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03/CstmrCdtTrfInitn"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 ns2">
<xsl:key name="PmtInfByPmtInfId" match="ns2:PmtInf" use="ns2:PmtInfId" />
<xsl:key name="group" match="ns2:PmtInf" use="ns2:PmtInfId"/>
<xsl:template match="ns2:PmtInf/ns2:PmtInfId 
| ns2:PmtInf/ns2:PmtInfId/ns2:PmtMtd 
| ns2:PmtInf/ns2:PmtInfId/ns2:PmtTpInf/SvcLvl/Cd 
| ns2:PmtInf/ns2:PmtInfId/ns2:ReqdExctnDt">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="ns2:PmtInf[count(. | key(group)[$id = generate-id(parent::*)][1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ns2:Dbtr/*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key(group)[$id = generate-id(parent::*)]/*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is giving no change in output.

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Short example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr></GrpHdr>
    To be Repeated once per PmtInfId >> Start
    <PmtInf>
      <PmtInfId></PmtInfId>
      <PmtMtd></PmtMtd>
      <PmtTpInf></PmtTpInf>
      <ReqdExctnDt></ReqdExctnDt>
    To be Repeated once per PmtInfId << End
    
      <Dbtr></Dbtr>
      <DbtrAcct></DbtrAcct>
      <DbtrAgt></DbtrAgt><!-- these should group by PmtInfId & repeated -->
      <ChrgBr></ChrgBr>
      <CdtTrfTxInf></CdtTrfTxInf>

      <Dbtr></Dbtr>
      <DbtrAcct></DbtrAcct><!-- these should group by PmtInfId & repeated -->
      <DbtrAgt></DbtrAgt>
      <ChrgBr></ChrgBr>
      <CdtTrfTxInf></CdtTrfTxInf>

    </PmtInf>
  </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

Comment: *"I am unaware of grouping the elements in XSLT."* Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. Come back if you have a **specific** question about the implementation.

Comment: Coudnt able to identify where i am misusing the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to group the `PmtInf` elements by the single `PmtInfId`? Or by the various values you have shown in your first snippet, e.g. `PmtMtd`, `Cd` and `ReqdExctnDt`? Are you restricted to XSLT 1? Since 2008 we have XSLT 2 and since 2017 we have XSLT 3 which are more powerful and more expressive than XSLT 1.  As for your example, it would help if you shortened them to the minimum relevant to demonstrate the problem, currently in the input and output sample, with all the data in there, it is hard to see which grouping/wrapping you want.

Comment: Yes, need to group the PmtInf elements by the single PmtInfId.
Yes, restricted to XSLT 1.

Comment: I suggest you reduce your example  (see: [mcve]) and add an explanation of what you're trying to do. I don't intend to go through hundreds lines of code to understand the difference between input and output.

Comment: In My example i need to group by PmtInfId, Then have to display its siblings, by repeating  the elements : Dbtr,DbtrAcct,DbtrAgt,ChrgBr,CdtTrfTxInf.

Comment: Updated a short example as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hesitate whether to answer this at all, because this is no more than a straightforward application of [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Your attempt is so sloppy as to raise doubts whether you have bothered to read it at all. It looks like you just slapped together some code in a vain hope that somehow it would work (which of course it doesn't).

Still, maybe you can learn something from the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="PmtInfByPmtInfId" match="ns1:PmtInf" use="ns1:PmtInfId" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:CstmrCdtTrfInitn">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ns1:GrpHdr"/>
        <!-- create a group for each unique PmtInfId -->
        <xsl:for-each select="ns1:PmtInf[count(. | key('PmtInfByPmtInfId', ns1:PmtInfId)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <!-- copy common items -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="ns1:PmtInfId | ns1:PmtMtd | ns1:PmtTpInf | ns1:ReqdExctnDt"/>
                <!-- copy items of current group members -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('PmtInfByPmtInfId', ns1:PmtInfId)">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ns1:Dbtr | ns1:DbtrAcct | ns1:DbtrAgt | ns1:ChrgBr | ns1:CdtTrfTxInf"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this assumes your XML has only one `CstmrCdtTrfInitn` element. Otherwise you would have to include its `id` in the grouping key, to avoid grouping across the  `CstmrCdtTrfInitn` boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and consideration.
Sorry, i have read you comment, then only added the example small xml by editing the main question.
May be this is not clear:
In My example i need to group by PmtInfId, Then have to display its siblings, by repeating the elements : Dbtr,DbtrAcct,DbtrAgt,ChrgBr,CdtTrfTxInf.
For this: i can say that:
i need to group by PmtInfId, (If PmtInfId is same, then All the elements: PmtInfId, PmtMtd, Id, PmtTpInf, ReqdExctnDt, will be same). So Grouping by PmtInfId, PmtMtd, Id, PmtTpInf, ReqdExctnDt is also correct and is what you said. Agreed.

Comment: Under the one PmtInf, there should be one set of PmtInfId, PmtMtd, Id, PmtTpInf, ReqdExctnDt. And the children Dbtr,DbtrAcct,DbtrAgt,ChrgBr,CdtTrfTxInf are to be repeated multiple.
Once again thanks for your patience and answer.
Let me know if i can send the sample file. I have no way to use other than XSLT Version 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 3, if all those listed values are meant to form the grouping key, you can use a composite key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="group" match="PmtInf" composite="yes" use="PmtInfId, PmtMtd, PmtTpInf/SvcLvl/Cd, ReqdExctnDt"/>

  <xsl:template match="PmtInf[. is key('group', PmtInfId)[1]]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*, tail(key('group', (PmtInfId, PmtMtd, PmtTpInf/SvcLvl/Cd, ReqdExctnDt)))/(* except (PmtInfId, PmtMtd, PmtTpInf, ReqdExctnDt))"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="PmtInf[not(. is key('group', (PmtInfId, PmtMtd, PmtTpInf/SvcLvl/Cd, ReqdExctnDt))[1])]"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehW12fD/1

XSLT 3 is supported on .NET and Java through Saxon 9.8 and later, through Saxon-JS 2 for Javascript and Node.js and through Saxon-C for C/C++ with bindings for Python and PHP.

Comment: Hi @Martin Honnen, Thanks for the above XSLT. If we wanted to remove the Duplicates of DbtrAcct, DbtrAgt, ChrgBr from the XML. Can you kindly tell me how can i achieve that please.

Comment: @XSLTLearner, ask a new question about that if you can't work it out with what you have learned, what introductions to grouping like https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info show you.